# PHP mail encoding: Is it possible to have special characters in the sender

Tags: php, email, encoding

Is it possible to have special characters like `ö, ä, ü, ß, ...` in the sender of a mail?

```
$sender = 'From: Mail with special characters öäüß <info@all.com>';
mail('somebody@nowhere.com', '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $sender);
```

Comment: It is not recommenced to use the build-in mail() function due lack of todays mail standards. Better using a mailer class like PHPMailer. This also should solves your character problem.

Comment: The mechanism is defined in RFC2047, basically the same as you are already doing for the Subject. But concur with others, don't reinvent the wheel poorly; use an existing library.

Comment: As long as you keep it to the name (the parts outside of the angle brackets) you should be fine. UTF8 characters in the address or the domain will not fly, based on our testing for [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$headers = "From: Info \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

    $mes=htmlspecialchars_decode($mes,ENT_QUOTES);//optional
    mail('somebody@nowhere.com', "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($sub)."?=", $mes, $headers);
```

But yes, using some mailer class is better option: [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Comment: I tried your header but it is still the same problem. The special character is not correctly shown (square with question marke in it). But I will have a look at PHPMailer.